# Apache and Virtual host returning NOT FOUND

Tags: php, apache, apache2, virtualhost, php-7

In

> apache httpd.conf

I changed `#Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` to `Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`.
Then, in

> httpd-vhosts.conf

I add this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/htdocs/drw-framework-master/public"
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName www.drw.localhost
    ServerAlias drw.localhost
    ErrorLog c:/Apache24/htdocs/logs/error.log
    Loglevel warn
    CustomLog c:/Apache24/htdocs/logs/access.log combined
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"

    <Directory C:/Apache24/htdocs/drw-framework-master/public>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        #Require all granted
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Options+Indexes
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And finally, in

> hosts file

in `windows/system32/driver` I added this to the file `127.0.0.1    drw.localhost`.

When I visit `drw.localhost` in the browser, it loads the index page but when I tried to visit other pages, it always returned

> error 404. NOT Found

Infact, this is the error

```
Not Found
The requested URL /register/new was not found on this server.
```

Meanwhile, inside the `public folder`, I have this code in the

> .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

**Edit**

This is what is inside the

> access.log

after viewing it

```
::1 - - [23/May/2020:14:35:26 +0100] "GET /register/new HTTP/1.1" 404 210 "http://drw.localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36"
```

**END EDIT**

I want to know where I go wrong in my configurations?

NB: Am running this on windows 8.1